# Shell script to fetch value of a node appearing multiple times in an XML

Tags: shell

I have a XML as below:

```
<artifact>
   <a>1.zip</a>
   <b>2-SNAPSHOT.zip</b>
   <c>3-SNAPSHOT.zip</c>
</artifact>
<artifact>
   <a>4.tar</a>
   <b>5.tar</b>
   <c>6.tar</c>
</artifact>
```

My requirement is to fetch the value "5.tar" coming in the 2nd appearance of node "artifact". I am able to fetch the value if this node is present only once in the XML. However, if the same node is appearing twice or multiple times in the same XML, I am not able to fetch it.

Please help.

Comment: `I have a XML as below ` <- this is not a well formed XML document

Comment: @ Pierre. This is a section of an XML from Jenkins API that is of my need. So, shared that section only. It is present under root.

Comment: @Inian: This is how I am fetching the value, if it is appearing only once:     export ver=$(echo 'cat //artifact/b/text()' | xmllint --shell BuildResult.xml)

Comment: @NishantKansal: Thanks for the update, please update the question with the above effort!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will break down the answer which I tried using [`xmllint`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xmllint)

```
$ echo "cat //root/artifact/b" |  xmllint --shell BuildResult.xml | sed '/^\/ >/d' | sed 's/<[^>]*.//g' | tr -d '\n' | awk -F"-------" '{print $2}'
5.tar
```

I have formatted your original `BuildResult.xml` file by adding `<root>` nodes and adding proprietary header information, to avoid any parsing errors:-

```
$ xmllint -format BuildResult.xml
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<root>
  <artifact>
    <a>1.zip</a>
    <b>2-SNAPSHOT.zip</b>
    <c>3-SNAPSHOT.zip</c>
  </artifact>
  <artifact>
    <a>4.tar</a>
    <b>5.tar</b>
    <c>6.tar</c>
  </artifact>
</root>
```

The steps as they executed:-

Starting the file parsing from root-node to the repeating node (`//root/artifact/b`) and running `xmllint` in interactive shell mode (`xmllint --shell`)

Running the command plainly produces a result,

```
/ >  -------
<b>2-SNAPSHOT.zip</b>
 -------
<b>5.tar</b>
/ >
```

Now removing the special characters using `sed` i.e. `sed '/^\/ >/d' | sed 's/<[^>]*.//g'` produces

```
2-SNAPSHOT.zip
 -------
5.tar
```

Now removing the newlines from the above command using `tr` so that `awk` can process the records using the field separator as `-------`

```
2-SNAPSHOT.zip -------5.tar
```

The `awk` command on the above output will produce the file as needed; `awk -F"-------" '{print $2}`

```
5.tar
```

Putting it together in a shell script, it looks like

```
#!/bin/bash

newVar=$(echo "cat //root/artifact/b" |  xmllint --shell BuildResult.xml | sed '/^\/ >/d' | sed 's/<[^>]*.//g' | tr -d '\n' | awk -F"-------" '{print $2}')
echo "$newVar"
```

P.S:- The number of commands can be reduced/simplified with a reduced number of `awk`/`sed` command combination. This is just a solution that works.

Comment: Thanks Inian for a detailed explanation of your answer. When, I am running this script, it is returning 2-SNAPSHOT.zip instead of 5.tar...:(

Comment: It is returning 5.tar with {print $3} instead of {print $2}. Thanks for all your help Inian,

Comment: Could you please help me for my post: bash script running correctly in linux machine but not when executed via jenkins from a windows machine

Comment: @NishantKansal: Please post it as a new question. Whatever you have asked is not within the scope of this.

Comment: I have already posted it as a new question with the heading: Bash script running correctly in Linux machine but not when executed via Jenkins from a Windows machine. Please have a look and suggest me.